# Isometric Drawing - filling in the blanks

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Im trying to write a small application that makes isometric shapes. Ive been able to make 
a cube / cuboid shape in the picture, but i need to be able to fill in the face of the cubes.

http://peterfleming.net84.net/cube.PNG

I used a drawLine method and mapped points but i was hoping there was an easier, perhaps a drawRectangle method that i could use instead and then fill them in, but so far i havent been able to find any, perhaps because of the isometric nature of the shape.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're after can be easily done with the [Polygon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.polygon.aspx) class.

Comment: Thanks, i looked at polygon earlier too and your right, it is the simplest way of implementing what i need and has worked.